# Use a formula to organize columns with different amounts of data

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

When each column is recorded, the values are different sizes:

[image]

I would like the values to be pulled to the left so that one column is always well adjusted with the others:

[image]

> Is there any way to do this using a formula?

link to Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iXqdjs_D-NvyES4LMjpzFEY4uDvbdcMZZY5VUvpmbRQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is no quite clear what you mean and how e.g. `Jogo: Empoli x Pisa` is supposed to get moved from column 4 to column 1. In any case it might be easier with Apps Script than with formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> values to be pulled to the left

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A1:D12<>"", 
 SUBSTITUTE(A1:D12, " ", "♦"), )),,999^99)), " "), "♦", " "))
```

[image: 0]

---

while equal distribution would be:

```
={FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A1:D12<>"", 
  SUBSTITUTE(A1:D12, " ", "♦"), )),,999^99)),,999^99), " ")), "♦", " "), 
  MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:D12)))-1, 4)=0), 
  FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A1:D12<>"", 
  SUBSTITUTE(A1:D12, " ", "♦"), )),,999^99)),,999^99), " ")), "♦", " "), 
  MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:D12)))-2, 4)=0), 
  FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A1:D12<>"", 
  SUBSTITUTE(A1:D12, " ", "♦"), )),,999^99)),,999^99), " ")), "♦", " "), 
  MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:D12)))-3, 4)=0), 
  FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A1:D12<>"", 
  SUBSTITUTE(A1:D12, " ", "♦"), )),,999^99)),,999^99), " ")), "♦", " "), 
  MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:D12)))-4, 4)=0)}
```

[image]

note that `=COUNTA(A1:D12)/4` needs to be a whole number otherwise you will get ARRAY error. to avoid ARRAY error you can use 1 formula per column. paste in A column and drag it till you reach D column:

```
=FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF($A$1:$D$12<>"", 
 SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$D$12, " ", "♦"), )),,999^99)),,999^99), " ")), "♦", " "), 
 MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA($A$1:$D$12)))-COLUMN(A1), 4)=0)
```